# Degree distribution of a graph of integer partitions

Tags: combinatorics, integer-partitions

Consider a graph whose nodes are the integer partitions of $n$, connected by an edge if you can get from one partition to the other by ‘sliding one square of its Young diagram’ – that is, if one partition can be gotten from the other by decrementing one of its values and either incrementing another value or adding a new value of 1.

I am interested in things like the degree distribution, mean degree, etc of this graph. Is anything known about this?

Comment: Open problem, as it turns out. If you're interested see some of K. Eriksson's papers.

Comment: Would you mind pointing to the specific papers of K. Eriksson?

Comment: @stackExchangeUser: e.g. 'Limiting shapes of birth-and-death processes on Young diagrams', Eriksson & Sjöstrand.